# Check Validity of Data Before Update Phase in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have data which updates every 10 seconds and I would like to check that all the data is valid before progressing with updates. I am currently getting false data intermittently which occurs as a negative number in one of the values. If one of the objects has a negative value then I don't trust the whole set and don't want to update any elements.

Ideally I don't want to update some items and then bail once the incorrect value occurs, but rather, determine if the whole set is good before updating anything

I'm not sure how d3 can manage this but I've tried with this and it seems to work. But it doesn't seem particularly in keeping with the elegance of D3 so I think there's probably a correct and better way to do it. But maybe not?!

```
var dataValid = true;
abcItems.each(function (d, i) {
    if (0 > dd.Number1 - dd.Number2) dataValid = false;
});
if (dataValid) {
    abcItems.each(function (d, i) {
        // updating elements here
    });
} else {
    console.log("negative value occurred");
}
```

Is there a better way to manage this through D3?

A little bit more context:

The data (JSON provided via a RESTful API) and visualisation (a bar chart) are updating every 10 seconds. The glitch in the API results in incorrect data once every hour or so at the most (sometimes it doesn't happen all day). The effect of the glitch is that the bars all change dramatically whereas the data should only change by ones or twos each iteration. In the next fetch of data 10 seconds later the data is fine and the visualisation comes right.

The data itself is always "well-formed" it's just that the values provided are incorrect. Therefore even during the glitch it is safe to bind the data to elements.

What I want to do, is skip the entire iteration and update phase if the data contains one of these negative values.

Perhaps also worth noting is that the items in the data are always the same, that is to say the only "enter" phase that occurs is on page load and there are no items that exit (though I do include these operations to capture any unexpected fluctuations in the data). The values for these items do change though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code it seams you already have bound the dataset to your DOM elements `abcItems.each(...)`.

Why not bail out of the update function when the data is not valid.

```
d3.json("bar-tooltip.json", function(dataset) {

    if (!dataset.every(d => d.Number2 <= d.Number1)) return;

    // do the update of the graph

    });
```

The example assumes you call `d3.json()` froma function that is called every update interval, but you can use a different update method.

Comment: Correct, there is data bound to the elements (the data is provided from an api). In hindsight the answer you provide is so simple - perhaps I was in a rut at the end of the work day and got into a fixed way of thinking! Yeah, I think I can bail out totally if the data isn't valid.

Comment: By the way, is `.every` an actual JS/D3 thing or is that kind of pseudo code? either way I understand the concept :)

Comment: @wunth: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every it should be available in any browser. You bind data to elements and then check if the data is valid and proceed with drawing?? This will result in inconsistencies and very hard bugs to find/fix.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I don't know why I didn't find it myself! I see what you mean. I should've described the data as not "sound" as it is only the values that are wrong, it is "valid" in that it is always well formed and safe to bind to elements. Also, the visualisation is already drawn, I wish to skip the redraw if a negative value (/glitch) occurs. Even in the very unlikely event that the page is loaded at the exact time of a glitch data will bind correctly and be reflected properly in the next 10 second iteration. This is why I only want to handle the issue during the update phase

Comment: @wunth: what you can do is show a text like "Waiting for data" in the svg. And the first step of the data handler callback is remove this text `svg.select("#waittext").remove()` and then draw the graph initialization if not done before (check presence of a unique `g` element) and then update the graph

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I have functions in place to fade out sections and show a loader when the data is initialised or if it drops out totally (such as when disconnecting the network). The data doesn't change much on each update so if the glitch occurs I'd rather just ignore it without highlighting it. But if it occurs on page load (which is probably what you're referring to) then I should hook in those functions to indicate that as you suggest, and probably shorten the time to the next `get`. Despite being a bit of an edge case I think it's an important one to handle - thanks.